# How to add social login feature to ASP.NET MVC site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, facebook

I'm looking to add Google/Facebook/Twitter/LinkedIN/etc.. login options to my site. Is there any "one-stop" solution for this? preferably Open-Source.

If not - how can they be incorporated easily?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) library will help you here.  There are APIs for OpenID (Google etc.) and FaceBook connect.  It's fairly straightforward to get it working with MVC, but OpenID etc. has it's quirks.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I think you'll get to something as contained as what you're asking for is [OpenID](http://openid.net/).

For anything that isn't supported by OpenID you'll need to incorporate that yourself. There's some information around here somewhere about how StackOverflow included Google login although I beleive it's changed somewhat since that time. I'll see if I can dig it out.

Answer (score 0):

For a pre-packaged product, you might want to check out http://www.janrain.com/products/engage .  It looks like a really good choice for a pre-packaged solution to this problem.  Commercial so it doesn't meet the Open Source requirement. :-/

Just to clarify, I am not associated with this company or product in any way other than as a developer thinking about using the tool myself.